# How to create Julia notebook in Juno similar to IJulia or R Notebook

Tags: julia, atom-editor, juno-ide

Is it possible to create a Julia notebook in Atom/Juno similar to IJulia (Jupyter Notebook) or R Notebook (RStudio IDE)?

What I am looking for is a format that can save the code input together with the calculated ouput and the output printed in the console in one chunk. I also would like to mix in Markdown between code chunks.

The reason for me not wanting to use IJulia is that I don't want to save my Julia code in JSON format. I want it to be as pure as possible.

Comment: You can export your IJulia file as raw Julia code if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Weave.jl](https://github.com/mpastell/Weave.jl), which promises:

> > Current features
>
> Noweb, markdown or script syntax for input documents.
>
> Execute code as terminal or "script" chunks.
>
> Capture Plots, Gadfly and PyPlot figures.
>
> Supports LaTex, Pandoc, Github markdown, MultiMarkdown, Asciidoc and
>   reStructuredText output
>
> Publish markdown directly to html and
>    pdf using Julia or Pandoc markdown.
>
> Simple caching of results
>
> Convert to and from IJulia notebooks

Comment: weave is great, it can now handle also bibtex citations : https://sylvaticus.gitbooks.io/julia-language-a-concise-tutorial/content/14-weave.html